# Undefined reference to typeinfo for decltype(nullptr)

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, clang, c++14

I tried to compile simple code `int main() { throw nullptr; }` and got an error:

```
/tmp/main-ea26ec.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `typeinfo for decltype(nullptr)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The command line is: `clang++ -std=gnu++1z -stdlib=libc++ -Ofast -march=native -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-newline-eof main.cpp -o a && ./a`. *clang++* version is `clang version 3.6.0 (tags/RELEASE_360/final 235480)` (from [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7ef3b03304be6bc)).

I look through related questions and there was an issues with `virtual` functions, but type `std::nullptr_t` is not class and has no member functions.

What is the source of the error?

I also tried to add `auto const & unused = typeid(std::nullptr_t);` to make force generation of *typeinfo* for `nullptr` (is it wrong?), but it gives nothing.

Comment: Thiso cmpile with gcc on coliru

Comment: @PaoloM yes, I already noted it.

Comment: `-lsupc++` fixes this on coliru.

Comment: It should be noted that option `-lsupc++` should be appended after `.cpp` file in command line of `clang`, but not prepended before one.

Comment: @T.C.: Since he is using libc++ he should link against `c++abi` and not `supc++`.

Comment: @Thomas It is certainly allowed to link libc++ against libsupc++. Their own website has [a section](http://libcxx.llvm.org/#libsupcxx) on that.

Comment: @Orient: Your code compiles fine for me with clang 3.5, clang-3.6 and clang-3.7 with libc++-3.6 and libc++abi-3.6 on Arch Linux.

Comment: @T.C.: I know it's allowed, but why on earth would you want to link the libstdc++ abi runtime when you are using libc++?

Comment: @Thomas Why wouldn't you? Just because of "purity"? Besides, coliru doesn't seem to have libc++abi, and using libcxxrt causes that code to segfault.

Comment: @T.C.: libc++abi doesn't code that code to segfault. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fehm29Ps

Comment: @Thomas Sure, I'm making the point that you can't use `-lc++abi` on coliru, because the library is not there.

Comment: @T.C.: You are right, `-lsupc++` is probably not much of an issue since supc++ is always linked statically. While, if possible, I would always prefer (and also recommend others) to use the toolchain's "native" implementation.